# My code seems to be skipping the return statement

Tags: java, recursion, return

I am wiriting a palindrome-checking boolean function in Java - I am learning recursion. When the word is stripped to the final (inner) one or two letters and the program should check if the two letters are the same it seems to not work - function always returns false.
It seems odd that when program comes to return, it just continues to work - I know this because it continues to print my checkpoints (print statements). The print function is executed, but the return statement right after is ignored. And even when the function should return true (=the word is a palindrome), at the end it still returns false.

I have already tried combinations of if, if-else statements, different positions of return statements, the function isPalindrome is working correctly with the main function and I have tried lots of debugging with print functions.

My code:

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String word) {
    int wlength = word.length();
    System.out.printf("wlength = %d%n", wlength);
    
    if (wlength == 1) {
        System.out.printf("wlength == 1!!!!%n");
        return true;

    } else if (wlength == 2) {
        System.out.printf("wlength == 2%n");
        String first = word.substring(0, 1);
        String last = word.substring(1, 2);
        if (first == last) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    String first = word.substring(0, 1);
    String last = word.substring(wlength-1, wlength);
    System.out.printf("first = %s, last = %s %n", first, last);
    if (first.compareTo(last) == 0) {
        System.out.printf("first == last%n");
        String inner= word.substring(1, wlength-1);
        System.out.printf("new Word = %s RECURSION%n", inner);
        isPalindrome(inner);
    } 
    System.out.println("END");
    return false;
    
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `prva` is undefined.

Comment: You're ignoring the return value of the inner call. All calls for lengths greater than 2 go at your last println and return false.

Comment: Can you provide an example input word that causes the problem and post the corresponding console output, it's quite hard for anyone to diagnose what's going on otherwise.  Suffice to say it definitely won't be 'ignoring' the return statement!

Comment: In addition to the already mentioned issues, you are comparing two strings with `==` and not with `equals()` or `equalsIgnoreCase()`

Comment: `isPalindrome(inner);` -> `return isPalindrome(inner);`

Comment: Also have you tried using a debugger to step through the code, it's a LOT more efficient than print statements.

Answer (score 2):

```java
if (prva.compareTo(last) == 0) {
    System.out.printf("first == last%n");
    String inner= word.substring(1, wlength-1);
    System.out.printf("new Word = %s RECURSION%n", inner);
    isPalindrome(inner); // <--- here
}
```

You haven't captured the return value on the last line shown above.